# Prevent Iron Router Not Found template showing when using angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

I have a Meteor application and I'm using a combination of angular-meteor and Iron Router routing.

Angular-meteor client side routing is used for all browser side routing and Iron Router is used for all server side routing. I'm implementing an OAuth2 server in Meteor so I need to be able to hit a URL without using the client side code.

The setup works great, but with one consequence: the Iron Router 'not found' template always shows on the client, because I have no client side routes for Iron Router:

[image]

I've also tried adding a blank Iron Router route to the client side code:

```
Router.route('(.*)', function(){
    //Do nothing
});
```

or

```
Router.route('(.*)', function(){
    //Do nothing
    this.ready();
});
```

But that results in all my angular-meteor templates being duplicated on the client:

[image]

I've also tried setting the Iron Router configuration to use a different not-found template I've written in Blaze, and using angular-with-blaze:

```
> meteor add angular-with-blaze
```

client & server code:

```
Router.configure({
    notFoundTemplate: "ironrouternotfound"
});
```

ironrouternotfound_blaze.html:

```
<template name="ironrouternotfound">
    IR Not Found
</template>
```

ironrouternotfound.html

```
<blaze-template name="ironrouternotfound"></blaze-template>
```

But that results in the following text being injected into the bottom on the HTML DOM:

```
Couldn't find a template named "ironrouternotfound" or "ironrouternotfound". Are you sure you defined it?
```

This message is injected by IronRouter and it doesn't have an ID on the div or any CSS classes so I can't hide it using JS or CSS. (Well, I might be able to hack a JS to remove the last div on the page, but that could be dangerous)

Any one managed to remove the Iron Router not-found view in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

My temporary CSS hack is:

```
div[style="margin: 0 auto; color: red;"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This appears to not work with Internet Explorer however

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. First declare a blank HTML template in a client folder like this:

```
<template name="noRoutesTemplate"></template>
```

Next in a common folder (eg. 'lib') add iron router's noRoutesTemplate to the configuration.

```
import { Router } from 'meteor/iron:router';

Router.configure({
 noRoutesTemplate: 'noRoutesTemplate',
});
```

See this reference [link](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/commit/bdb65840386a7558cc5e91047230ef94450ea96a)